# Remove leading characters from strings

Tags: sql-server

I need to remove the leading characters from a string column (sample data below). You'll notice that the values are prefixed with `a.` or `b.` or `c.` and a variable number of spaces. I can use a `REPLACE` function but I'll need to do that for each scenario independently as the length of spaces varies. Is there a clever way of stripping these out so that the output rows have `Name1` `Name2` `Name3`?

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ID  |                       Name                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   a.    Name1                                   |
|   2   |   b.          Name2                             |
|   3   |   c. Name3                                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Divide the string after the third character (or after ". " depending on the variability) and trim the second part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query in SQL Server 2017.

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Name, CHARINDEX('.', [Name]), LEN([Name])), '.', '') 
FROM TableName
```

and results will be as per your expected.

Comment: Thanks @Kishan! I've used your solution with a slight modification to handle `non-breaking space` (`ASCII 160`)

Comment: Thanks @Dale for suggest me proper way to post Answer and thanks for editing.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
select ID, trim(substring([Name], 3, len([Name])-2)) [Name]
from
  (values (1, 'a.    Name1        '),
          (2, 'b.          Name2                            '),
          (3, 'c. Name3')) v(ID, [Name]);
```

Results

```
ID  Name
1   Name1
2   Name2
3   Name3
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven! `trim` doesn't work for me, so I replaced that with `LTRIM`. Though, funnily, `SELECT LTRIM('      Name1')` doesn't remove the leading space - is it because SQL thinks it's not whitespace and something else?

Comment: Did you try ltrim(rtrim(...))?

Comment: Yes, I did - same result. `select ltrim('      Name1'), ltrim('    Name1')`. You'll notice that the 2nd `LTRIM` removes the spaces but the first doesn't. In the 2nd, I've manually added a few spaces before `Name1`, while the 1st is copied from the database column. (Not sure if copy-pasting this statement into here will convert the 1st one to spaces though)

Comment: I'm going to try patindex.  I think there's an xml way to do it too

Comment: I just checked the `ASCII` value and it appears to be `160` instead of the normal`32` that's for space. That's probably why  `LTRIM` isn't able to remove it.

Comment: I've just applied `LTRIM` along with a `REPLACE NCHAR(160)` to handle `non-breaking space` and it's worked! Thanks for your help¬